# After cloning any flutter project I can not resolve dependencies?

Tags: flutter, dart, clone, flutter-dependencies

I want to clone open source projects, I face a hole punch of errors after tapping pub get, all dependencies cannot be resolved and many of the code is out of date, so how can I overcome this?

[image: a sample of errors]

Answer (score 1):

Please use intl 0.17.0 to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the conflict between dependency versions.
You are using two dependencies that need different version of `intl`:

1. `flutter_localization`
2. `openfluttercommerce`

in your `pubspec.yaml` change the version of `intl` from `0.16.0` to `0.17.0`. It may cause another conflict with other dependencies that may depend on `0.16.0` version of `intl`. If it accurs, you need to change the version of utilized dependencies to whatever need the same version of `intl`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you clone the project from Github try to open it with flutter sdk version 1.17.0 or 1.22.4 after seeing the first commit of the project then the problem seems to be solved.

but here it seems that you got problem with two dependencies try to resolve that by not mentioning any version in yuml file.

Answer (score 0):

run this

(   flutter pub add cupertino_icons:^1.0.6     )

on terminal of you project directory it resolve the problem

and with pubspec.yaml->environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <4.0.0"  this one makes to take any version of dart and flutter

then run flutter pub get